# regex - find all occurrences within a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string: "[2-0]>5&&[3-0]<21"

I would like to pull out an array of: 2-0 and 3-0

The resulting array should look like this: ["2-0", "3-0"]

Does anyone know some fancy regex that will do this, or perhaps another method?

Comment: you wanna search for text in the brackets?

Comment: Have you tried any regex yet?

Comment: i am wondering why someone did that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the below code which matches the strings present inside the `[]` brackets,

```
> "[2-0]>5&&[3-0]<21".match(/[^\[\]]+(?=\])/g)
[ '2-0', '3-0' ]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I will mark as correct in a few mins.

Answer (score 2):

```
  \[(.*?)\]
```

This should be your fancy regex.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yZ7hR7/1

Comment: Fast, and close, but not 100% as it still has the brackets. Thanks though!

Comment: @Rich it cannot have brackets as they are not captured.Look at the demo.

Comment: @vks in js, you have to write some more js code to print the characters which are present inside captured group.